# LongListSelector selected item issue navigating back

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm writing a WP8 app.
In the mainpage I've a longlistselector, if I tap an item and navigate to another page, when I press the back button from the second page and come back to the mainpage if I tap the same item again nothing happens, but if I tap a different item it works as it should.
_Here it is the ode for the function of the listener of the lls

```C#
private void MessageList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageList.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Contact c = (Contact)MessageList.SelectedItem;

    long id = c.ID;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ChatPage.xaml?ID=" + id.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));

    MessageList.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

As you can see I've already resetted the selected item, but the lls behaves the same way

Hope you can help me, thanks in advice!

Comment: I think your problem is that you've set `SelectedItem` to null.  coming back the list probably thinks you haven't clicked on something new and doesn't set `SelectedItem` to the clicked item.  Try not setting it to `null`.

Comment: I added .SelectedItem = null; to try to solve this problem, but it didn't help me... It behaves the same way if I comment that line

Answer (score 0):

Try handling it in the `OnNavigatedTo` event

```C#
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    MessageList.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Then your `SelectionChanged` gets changed to:

```C#
private void MessageList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageList.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    Contact c = (Contact)MessageList.SelectedItem;
    long id = c.ID;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ChatPage.xaml?ID=" + id.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
}
```